# How to validate which condition in the drools rule is failing?

Tags: drools, rules

I am using drools 7.44 and have a package with more than 20+ rules. Currently i am facing the issue that i sometimes certain rules that i expect to fire are not firing.
In the **then** i can add log statements but not in the **when**.
Is there a way to debug or log which condition of the rules are failing?

If Customer age=21 gender=male and the below rule is used. How can i determine at runtime that the gender is the criteria is causing the rule to not fire.

```
rule "some rule"
    when
        $c : Customer(age>18 , gender == "female" )
    then
........
        do something here
        log.debug("something to log") 
end
```

This is a simple example to illustrate the problem. Ideally we have multiple conditions.

Comment: Do you want a logging solution or a debugging solution? You might want to start logging your actual rule hits and see if something that triggers first perhaps calls `retract` on the inputs or modifies them or something.

Comment: Basically i want to know why a certain rule condition has not evaluated, so that i can pin point the exact condition.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DebugAgendaEventListener` to trace the rules evaluation. See the [manual](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.54.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_event_model)

This will cover only the case when the match succeeds. If not, nothing will be evaluated. There's a [JIRA](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DROOLS-6368) to track such failed evaluation

Extract from the manual

> The Drools engine also supports the following agenda and working
> memory event listeners for debug logging:

`DebugAgendaEventListener`
`DebugRuleRuntimeEventListener`

> These event listeners implement the same supported event-listener
> methods and include a debug print statement by default. You can add a
> specific supported event to be monitored and documented, or monitor
> all agenda or working memory activity.
>
> For example, the following code uses the DebugRuleRuntimeEventListener
> event listener to monitor and print all working memory events:
>
> Example code to monitor and print all working memory events

```
ksession.addEventListener( new DebugRuleRuntimeEventListener() );
```

Comment: This does not exactly mention which condition fails.

Comment: I see your point @Technical101, but nowhere in the execution we trace whether a Pattern has matched or not: the output would be too verbose to understand. If you need to know where it doesn't match, I suggest you go low-level and step with the debugger into the `assertMethod` method of `AlphaNode` .

Comment: The problem is that want to do this at runtime.

Comment: @Technical101 I filed a JIRA for that https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DROOLS-6368

Comment: Thanks @Luca Molteni